# Array external linkage and MISRA 8.12

Tags: arrays, c, struct, linkage

I have a program that needs to load fonts into a display according to language ID.

I would like to have a structure containing the attributes for writing the font data:

```
typedef struct Font_Data_Metrics_s
{
    uint8_t const * font_data_start;
    size_t          font_data_length;
    unsigned int    language_id;
} Font_Data_Metrics_t;
```

The font data are in separate files, one font per file.
Example:
Russian_Font_Data.c:

```
uint8_t const Russian_Font_Data[] =
{
  // the data
};
const size_t Size_Russian_Font_Data =
    sizeof(Russian_Font_Data) / sizeof(Russian_Font_Data[0]);
```

Ideally, I'd like to use (outside of Russian_Font_Data.c):

```
const static Font_Data_Metrics_t russian_metrics =
{
  Russian_Font_Data,       // This field is the annoying issue.
  Size_Fussion_Font_Data,
  6, // Russian language ID
};
```

Here's what I've tried:
(1) `extern uint8_t const Russian_Font_Data[];`
Error: When an array is declared with external linkage, its size shall be stated explicitly or defined implicitly by initialisation (MISRA C 2004 rule 8.12)

(2) `extern uint8_t const * Russian_Font_Data;`
Error: Declaration is incompatible with "uint8_t const * Russian_Font_Data"

(3) `uint8_t const font_data_start[];` (inside the struct).
Illformed when inside the structure.

How can place the address of an array, with external linkage, into a struct?
(Preferably without <s>annoying</s> MISRA violations)

**Edit 1: Background / Usage**
I want a table of metrics for over 12 fonts.  The table will be searched by language ID.  The font data start and font data length will be passed to a function that writes the data to a hardware display device.  Other code in the project will be setting the language ID based on the Operator's selection.

Presently, I have a table that is built during run-time by calling "data" functions.  This is messy and I'll need "getter" functions for each font.  My objective is to have a table with constant data, that can be placed and directly accessed from the data segment (in other words, ready for access before the program starts).

Comment: BTW, there is a typo: `Size_Fussion_Font_Data`.

Comment: Does `const uint8_t *const Russian_Font_Data_Ptr = Russian_Font_Data;` inside `Russian_Font_Data.c` and using this as an initalizer for `russian_metrics` work?

Comment: Couldn't you define the `russian_metrics` variable in Russian_Font_Data.c with external linkage and declare it `extern` in a header file?

Comment: Initializing `russian_metrics.font_data_length` with `Size_Russian_Font_Data` (or `Size_Fussion_Font_Data` :-) ) is a constraint violation. It should be initialized with a constant expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can define the metrics and the font data in the same .c file:

**In Russian_Font_Data.c:**

```
#include "Font_Data_Metrics.h"

const static uint8_t Russian_Font_Data[] =
{
  // the data
};

const Font_Data_Metrics_t russian_metrics =
{
  .font_data_start = Russian_Font_Data,
  .font_data_length = sizeof Russian_Font_Data / sizeof Russian_Font_Data[0],
  .language_id = 6, // Russian language ID
};
```

**In some header file**:

```
#include "Font_Data_Metrics.h"

extern const Font_Data_Metrics_t russian_metrics;
```

Comment: I was just thinking about something like this, but using a "getter" function.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews That won't really help you - instead of accessing `russian_metrics` directly, you'd have to call `get_russian_metrics()`.  Either way, you have to access some symbol in the file.